# Doctrine - Unable to persist entity with composite key

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, yaml, composite-primary-key

I'm using Doctrine with YML mappings. I have two entities. One `Group` entity and one `User` entity.

I'm trying to set it up so `User`s have unique names within a group.

I can create a `User`, assign it a `Group`, and save it to the DB. But when I try to create a `User` with the same name and a different `Group`, then I get an error saying the unique constraint on `name` is violated.

Why can't I persist that `User`?

Their mappings look like this:

```
Entity\Group:
    type: entity
    table: groups
    id:
        id:
            type: guid
            nullable: false
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: text
            nullable: true

Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: users
    id:
        group:
            associationKey: true
            nullable: false
        name:
            type: string
    manyToOne:
        Group:
            targetEntity: Entity\Group
            joinColumn:
                name: group
                referencedColumnName: id
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured this out. I was confusing Doctrine.

The non-standard thing was that I'm using a capitalized parameter name to represent an object and changing that to lowercase for the table column. I did this in the `manyToOne:` section using `name:`.

The documentation doesn't really do this, so I didn't know that I still had to reference the capitalized property name in the `id:` section and separately define the column name there.

So, I changed the `User` mapping to this:

```
Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: users
    id:
        Group:
            column: group
            associationKey: true
            nullable: false
        name:
            type: string
    manyToOne:
        Group:
            targetEntity: Entity\Group
            joinColumn:
                name: group
                referencedColumnName: id
```